# How to open a connection with a host that uses GoogleOauth2Service

Tags: c#, sockets, single-sign-on

I use a socket to open a connection with a host that uses Google SSO, however, I don't know how to provide my google credentials and send it with the socket to access the home page.

public static void Start() {

```
        byte[] bytes = new byte[2097152];
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("myhost.net");
            IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 80);

            Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                    sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                // Encode the data string into a byte array.    
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET /Home HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: myhost.net\r\n" + "Content-Length: 0\r\n" + "\r\n");
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

                // Receive the response from the remote device.    
                int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

                // Release the socket.    
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: Why are you using sockets instead of a HTTP or Web method?  The webpage expects HTTP format and TCP will not automatically add the required tags to be HTTP.

Comment: I still get as a response from the server html data, the pop up that requires Gmail authentication, but I don't know how to send the credentials.

Comment: Did you read following : https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en

Comment: I think there should be something that needs to be provided at the beginning before making HTTP requests.

Comment: I think there should be something that needs to be provided at the beginning before making HTTP requests.

Comment: Why do you think something else needs to be provided?

Comment: I mean Google credentials like client ID and password.

Comment: Google want to be setup to work with Chrome.   So in the request you have to specify in the headers user agent to be Chrome.  See : https://dotnetfiddle.net/pmcv26